# Rest api, node.js fails to find routes

Tags: node.js, express

Started working on rest api using node.js.Badly stuck with a problem no idea how to fix it. Prints error on calling http://localhost:8080/api/write/v1.0/login

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/app.js:38:16
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
                <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
                    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
                        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
                            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
                                <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
                                    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/Volumes/Developer/Node Sample/sample/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

App.js

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dbUtils = require('./utility/dbUtilties.js');

var config = require('./config/config.js');
var  api = require('./api/api');


// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
//router.get('/', function(req, res) {
//    var params = req.body;
//    var db = dbUtils.connect();
//    if(db){
//        console.log(db);
//    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
//    }else{
//        res.json({ message: 'connection failed' });
//    }
//});


app.all('/api/write/'+config.WRITE_API_VERSION+'/:apiName', function (req, res) {

    console.log("in api end1");

    api.handle.apply('write' , req.method.toLowerCase(), 'req.params.apiName', req, res);
});

app.all('/api/read/'+config.READ_API_VERSION+'/:apiName', function (req, res) {

        console.log("in api end2");

    api.handle.apply('read' , req.method.toLowerCase(), req.params.apiName, req, res);
});


// more routes for our API will happen here

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Api.js

```
var userAuth = require('./userAuth');

//api list  
var apiMiddleware = {
    read : {
        get : {
        },

        post : {
            'login': userAuth.signin,
        }
    },
    write : {
        post : {
            'signup' : userAuth.signup,
        },

        get : {
        }
    }
}



function Api(type, method,req,res){
    this.type = type;
    this.method = method;
    this.api = api;
    this.req = req;
    this.res = res;
}


Api.prototype = {
    constructor: Api,
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        //handle get request
        console.log(this.type,this.method,this.api);
        var apiHandler = ((apiMiddleware[this.type]||{})[this.method] || {})[this.api];

        if (apiHandler) {
            apiHandler.call(this, this.req);
        } 
        else {
            this.notFound();
        }
    }
}



//all api request will pass through this function
function handleRequest(type, method, api, req, res) {
    //to get to pass arguments in api
   // var arg = util.objToAry(arguments).slice(2, this.length);

    //create apiObject

         console.log("in api argument");

    var apiObj = new Api(type, method, api, req, res);


    // initialize api
    apiObj.init();
}

//to export handleRequest
module.exports.handle = handleRequest;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite explicit:

> TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

[`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) signature is `fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`, it expects an object (or null) followed by an array, you're passing a string first. Your `apply` call should look like:

```
api.handle.apply(null, ['write', req.method.toLowerCase(), 'req.params.apiName', req, res]);
```

If you don't have any specific reason to use `apply` (like setting `thisArg` to a specific value), you can simply call the function:

```
api.handle('write', req.method.toLowerCase(), 'req.params.apiName', req, res);
```